# Script to ensure the correct type of a field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

During the execution of an application script, I'm getting errors like :

```
failed with error 16837: "The field 'tags' must be an array but is of type String in document {_id: ObjectId('4f870265bb94786e84002f56')}"
```

It seems that the object mapper is saving an array in the field named tags, but some of my existing documents have an empty string or null value for this field.

So, I would like to create a script that would go through all existing records, and if the tags value is not an array would replace it by an empty array.
Is it the best solution for you? How would I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: This might help http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should basically work, and without looping:

```js
 db.collection.update(
     { 
         "$or": [ 
             { 
                 "field.0": { "$exists": false },
                 "field": { "$ne": [] } 
             },
             { "field": { "$exists": false }  },
         ]
     },
     { "$set": { "field": [] }},
     { "multi": true }
 )
```

So if the field is not a non-empty array or not present at all then replace it with an empty one. Multi updates everything.

Here's an example:

```js
{ "field" : "a" }
{ "field" : null }
{ "field" : [ "A" ] }
{ "field" : [ ] }
{ "abc" : "abc" }
```

Then run the update and:

```js
{ "field" : [ ] }
{ "field" : [ ] }
{ "field" : [ "A" ] }
{ "field" : [ ] }
{ "abc" : "abc", "field" : [ ] }
```

And only "three" of the documents are actually touched by the update.

Comment: Your answer is great. However in my case, in some documents the tags field is correct and already an empty array or a non-empty array. So I may have to use the loop to detect when the field is an empty string or a null value.

Comment: @NicolasBlanco This doesn't touch any array that actually has something in it, and if it is actually empty who cares? You could filter out actual empty arrays with a condition. Does this need more explanation with a sample?  You should not need to loop.

Comment: Yes that seems perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to iterate over all of your documents and inspect each one individually:

```js
db.collection.find().forEach( function( doc ) {
  if ( !Array.isArray( doc.tags ) ) {
    // tags is not an array! Correct it.
    doc.tags = Array( doc.tags );
    // save the document after modifications
    db.collection.save( doc );
  }
} );
```